# Does Tensorflow has a keras module?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, tensorflow, anaconda

everyone. I am a Geophysicist who has recently started learning Data Science. As part of this process I am going over some example source code included in the book "Machine Learning for the Oil and Gas Industry". The problem I have is that the source code has the following lines of code:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor, KerasClassifier
```

The first two lines seem to run correctly, however a ModuleNotFoundError is raised for the third line. I use Anaconda individual distribution and installed Tensorflow using Anaconda Navigator in my base environment.

Is there any way to get this to run properly?

Comment: I have the same problem. I hope someone can help us on that.

Comment: From another question I received the following advice which fixed my problem:
"Can you try to create a fresh env with conda create -n tf tensorflow=2.1, then do conda activate tf and python -c "import tensorflow;import tensorflow.keras?"

Comment: Hi, Peter, thanks for your answer. It was useful. I think you might find the answer provided by ncasas helpful. I think the advice you were given solved your problem because keras was still a module for that version of tensorflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import from `tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn`.

The confusion comes because there are 2 different Keras:

1. At the beginning, Keras was independent from tensorflow. At that time, you had to install Keras separately from tensorflow and its packages were `keras.*`. This version of Keras still exists but it is no longer maintained, but there are a lot of old blog posts and StackOverflow questions that still contain references to `keras.*`.
2. Later, Tensorflow absorbed Keras into its `tensorflow.keras.*` packages. This is the only currently maintained version of Keras.

If you want to know more about the relation between Keras and Tensorflow I suggest you take a look at [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/65754/14675).

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the third line with the following import

`from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor, KerasClassifier`

Hope this helps.